# Delete words made with print()

Tags: python-3.x

I want to make code so that a number goes from 1 to 2 to 3 and so on.

I am running this on Python 3. I have tried:

```
import time
from sys import stdout
for i in range(1,20):
    stdout.write("\r%d" % i)
    stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
stdout.write("\n") # move the cursor to the next line
```

But with that code, I get 12345678910111213141516171819.
Can someone help?
EDIT: I ran this code from the console, not from IDLE and it works. Can anyone explain?

Comment: works well with my test. my os is win10, and tested python2, python3

Comment: Not sure why do you need this, if you just want to print numbers in order - 1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2.... etc there could be multiple approach one could be run a loop print these numbers and create an exit condition may be based on counter of this sequence.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I think they mean "overwrite" instead of "delete".

Comment: BTW you don't need `sys.stdout` for this. `print("\r%d" % i, end='', flush=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my setup it works (Arch Linux, Python3). Do you start from IDE? Or from console?

Maybe another way works for you:

```
import time
from sys import stdout
for i in range(1,20):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    stdout.write("\033[F") #back to previous line
    stdout.write("\033[K") #clear line
stdout.write("\n") # move the cursor to the next line
```

Idea found [here](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-delete-the-last-printed-line-in-Python-language). This example works in my console but not when I start from PyCharm directly.

Comment: I get:1
[F[K2
[F[K3
[F[K4
[F[K5
[F[K6
[F[K7
[F[K8
[F[K9
[F[K10
[F[K11
[F[K12
[F[K13
[F[K14
[F[K15
[F[K16
[F[K17
[F[K18
[F[K19[F[K

Comment: Also, I ran your code from python shell but I did my code with a script. PS I'm using IDLE